# Laravel Server won't start properly

Tags: php, laravel

I installed Laravel today. When I finished the installation process
I tried to launch it but it stack it
I don't know how to solve the problem here is some picture of what I have done
by the way I started the xampp server and stopped it and I get the same result

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: is that your project file name is onda?

Comment: yes it's my project

Comment: is there any error displaying in browser?

Comment: No there is no error in the browser

Comment: then, what appears on your screen?

Comment: show me the final screen. is it keep loading?

Comment: Try to give write permissions to storage directory

Comment: @dilusha_dasanayaka yeah it keep loading

Comment: Did you copy the `.env.example` to `.env` and did you run `php artisan key:generate`?

Comment: @devk what is this
should i copy all the info from .env.example to .env
https://imgur.com/a/MypZv
https://imgur.com/a/pZ4LV

Comment: You don't need to copy everything, you can configure it yourself - [configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#environment-configuration)

Comment: Please attach your routes.php file too.

Comment: have you checked the apache error logs?

Comment: i finally solve the problem i just chnaged the port from 8000 to 5000
and it worked thx alot for help
sorry for my english